# InvalidOperationException was unhandled - WPF Path

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls, path

Here is my UserControl

```xml
<Grid x:Name="Grid">
    <Path Name="Path1" Data="M0.5,0.5 L179.5,0.5 L179.5,249.5 L0.5,249.5 z" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Purple" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" Opacity="0.4"/>
        </Path.Fill>
    </Path>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Path_Ani">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="Path1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-58.515"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="Path1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-129.167"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Path1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.544"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Path1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.806"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(SkewTransform.AngleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Path1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="5.628"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Data).(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[1].(LineSegment.Point)" Storyboard.TargetName="Path1">
                <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="100.5,140.5"/>
                <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="104.175476605516,140.5"/>
            </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

And i call the StoryBoard like that:

```
private void MyTest_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard sbdCardAnim = (Storyboard)MyTest.Grid.Resources["Path_Ani"];
    sbdCardAnim.Begin();
}
```

And i get this error when i click:

```
'[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[3].(2)'.
```

How do I solve the problem that is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animation expects the path to have a bunch of transformations defined as the `RenderTransform`, however your path's actual `RenderTransform` seems to be null (as it is not defined).

```xml
    <!-- The RenderTransform which is expected looks something like this
         (while no animation targets the third and therefore unknown transform
         it only makes sense for it to be a RotateTransform) -->
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform />
            <SkewTransform />
            <RotateTransform />
            <TranslateTransform />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
```

The path in the PointAnimation also does not seem to fit the actual data in the path as there will still be an error if the RenderTransform is defined as expected.